# input method hangs with mayavi import in Anaconda 3.5.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, freeze, mayavi

I have an input line that asks the user to hit enter to continue. This is so that they have time to read some things at the end of the program before it exits (when I build an exe).

I recently moved from a custom Python 3.6 environment to using Anaconda for Python 3.5.5 and now the code will hang after the input statement if the user hits enter without actually entering a character.

My script imports `mayavi`, and when I remove that import line, the problem goes away. I really like using mayavi and just spent 3 days getting everything to freeze correctly, so I would prefer to keep using it.

Example:

```
junk = input('Please press enter!')
```

If the user hits enter, the program just hangs. However, if you input a then hit enter, it works as expected. How can I get it to continue without entering any characters and simply hitting enter?

**EDIT**

For more details, I am running this in Visual Studio Code on Windows using an Anaconda Python 3.5.5 environment. It doesn't matter where in the code I run it. I thought this occurred no matter what but I started stripping imports and it started working again. I am importing a custom class, tkinter, xlwings, numpy, traceback, mayavi.mlab, sys, time, win32api.GetSystemMetrics, and win32com.client.gencache. I will continue to go through and see if it is a particular import.

Also, this is all running in a wrapper function, so I don't know if that matters. Also, I have heard the issues with catching any exception but this works how I want it.

```
def main_wrapper():
    # wrapper for main program to catch any exceptions and display them to the user
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Unexpected exception occurred...')
        traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_wrapper()
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your error on my side

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - the problem must be in a different part of the program.

Comment: Maybe don't store it in a variable ? Just use `input()`.

Comment: Pls provide full code. `input` does not yield described error.

Comment: may be share your environment details, running on windows or ubuntu? interactive shell or script? jupyter-notebook or some other IDE?